# Unable to install Flash Builder 4 plugin - Configuration Error 6

Tags: eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

I'm trying to install the Flash Builder 4 plugin for eclipse on my Mac.
The installation completes but when i launch eclipse i get the following pop-up message, after which eclipse quits unexpectedly.
[image]

I'm using the eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-macosx-carbon version of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  The solution on this site worked for me:
http://www.webappsolution.com/wordpress/2010/10/08/mac-flash-builder-plugin-install-error-6-fix/